# Python: Docstrings are not being updated

Tags: python, python-2.7, docstring

I have a docstring on the very first line of a Python file called a_file.py:

```
"""some text"""
```

When I print this using

```
import a_file
print a_file.__doc__
```

it prints `some text` as exptected.  However, whenever I change the docstring to

```
"""different text"""
```

it still prints `some text`.  I have made sure the file was saved with the changes.  I have a feeling that there is something very simple that I am just overlooking.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have read over the [python page on docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) but still no luck.

EDIT:
 SOLVED - I have figured it out.  Basically, I have a makefile which creates a new file.  I was printing from the new file when I thought I was actually printing from the source file. When I re-ran the makefile with the edited text, all was well.

Comment: How are you changing the docstring?

Comment: I am literally changing the text between the triple quotes and the output will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Are you editing the module's doctstring ?
If so, you'll need to reimport the file as its docstring is now in the memory. Use [reload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) for this
If not, this code works:

```
>>> def a():
...     """ hello """
...     print 'aa'
... 
>>> a.__doc__
' hello '
>>> a.__doc__ = 'bla bla'
>>> a.__doc__
'bla bla'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried to re-import the file, but it still is the same.

Comment: Edited my answer with the reload function, have a look and test it ;-)

Comment: Tried the reload function and still the same.